# Function $f(x)$, such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) x^n = f(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, functional-equations

Consider a function $f(x)$. Define Taylor series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) x^n$. Is there such a function, other than constant $0$, that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) x^n = f(x)$?

The Taylor series of $f(x)$ at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$. The series is unique, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) x^n.$ This means that $f^{(n)}(0)=f(n) n!$. The constant function $0$ meets this condition. Are there others?

Add: There is an almost similar question here: [Is there a function with the property $f(n)=f^{(n)}(0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91855/is-there-a-function-with-the-property-fn-fn0?rq=1)  It is not same, but looks a bit similar. Can it be used in any way?

---

A positive answer to this question has been obtained in [Does there exist a function that generates itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4772755/1018325).

Comment: Not really. The link is about function(s) with the property $f(n)=f^{(0)}(0)$, which is different from the property $n!f(n)=f^{(0)}(0)$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that this is impossible. For $f(1)$ to exist it must be that $f(n) \rightarrow 0$. But $\sum_n f(n) x^n$ is increasing in $x$ if any $f(n) > 0$.

Comment: Actually I'm an idiot. Obviously $f(n)$ may be negative. Then it seems $f(n)$ must change signs infinitely often or else the last nonzero term in the sum will dominate for sufficiently large $x$, and yet $f(n) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You need to add the further condition that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is infinite, to avoid trivial examples like $f(x)=1/(1-x)$ for $x<1$ with $f(x)=1$ otherwise.

Comment: This may be trivial, but it helps that for any function $f(0)=f(0)0!$, so we only need to concern ourselves with the derivatives

Comment: What is the point of adding a bounty without clarifying the questions asked by @JohnBentin in the comments?

Comment: Probably one of the most annoying problems I've ever spent 2 hours on without any gain.

Answer (score 11):

Far from a solution, but a few thoughts:

Say that an entire function is $n$-fine if $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, and $f^{(k)}(0)=f(k)k!$ for $0\le k\le n$.

For $n\ge 2$, consider the polynomial $$p_n(x)=x^{n}(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!x^{n}+O(x^{n+1}).$$
Then for $0\le k<n$, we have $p_n^{(k)}(0)=p_n(k)=0$, whereas $p_n(n)=n^n (n-1)!$ and $p_n^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^{n-1}n!(n-1)!$.
In particular, $$p_n(n)n!-p_n^{(n)}(0)=(n^n+(-1)^n)n!(n-1)!\ne0.$$

Thus,

> **Lemma.** If $f$ is $n$-fine, $n\ge 1$, then there exists a unique $c$ such that $f+cp_{n+1}$ is $(n+1)$-fine.

Given a 1-fine function $f_1$, in its most general form  $f_1(x)=x+x^2g(x)$, we use the lemma to recursively define a sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ such that $f_n$ is $n$-fine and $f_{n+1}-f_n$ is a multiple of $p_{n+1}$.

The question is: Does $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ exist?
As $x^n\mid p_n$, the limit certainly exists as a *formal* power series.
This gives us a linear map $g\mapsto f$ from entire functions (or even formal  power series) to formal power series, and we are looking for a fixed-point of this map ...

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but it seems to be an interesting observation, and it's too long for the comments, so I write it here. The point of this answer is to show that the real difficulty lies in ensuring that the required condition holds for all $x$, because it is extremely easy to get a construction if the condition is only to be satisfied on a bounded interval, even if you require smoothness everywhere on $\mathbb R$ (and analyticity almost-everywhere). In fact, there is so little difficulty in making such a  construction that any values of the $f(n)$ that you pick by hand will work (modulo some issues about convergence, so e.g. you can't pick values that diverge too quickly).

> **Claim.** For any sufficiently nice sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ (e.g. boundedness suffices), it is possible to find a *smooth* function
> $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(n)=a_n$ for positive
> integers $n$, as well as $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum f(n)x^n$ *in a
> neighbourhood of zero*.

To construct such a function we will exploit the fact that smooth functions are easy to bend around to our will, for example using bump functions. Let
$$ \sigma_{a,b}(x):=\begin{cases}1,&|x|\leq a\\\dfrac{\exp(-\frac{b-a}{x-a})}{\exp(-\frac{b-a}{x-a})+\exp(-\frac{b-a}{b-x})},&a<|x|<b,\\0,&|x|\geq b\end{cases}$$
be a smooth transition function from $1$ on the interval $(-a,a)$ to $0$ for $|x|\geq b$ for any real numbers $0<a<b$.

*Proof.* Let $f_r\colon (1-\epsilon,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be any smooth function that interpolates the $a_n$, i.e. $f_r(n)=a_n$ for all $n\geq1$, for some fixed $\epsilon>0$. I claim that we can construct a function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which restricts to $f_r$ on $(1-\epsilon,\infty)$ with the desired properties. To do so consider the function on a neighbourhood of $0$ defined by $g\colon (-r,r)\to\mathbb R, g(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ (where $r$ is the radius of convergence of this series). Let $\epsilon'>0$ be any real number smaller than $\min\{r,1-\epsilon\}$. Then, the function $$f(x)=g(x)\sigma_{\epsilon',(1-\epsilon)}(x)+f_r(x)$$ has the desired properties with the identity $f(x)=\sum f(n)x^n$ holding in the neighbourhood $(-\epsilon',\epsilon')$. (Of course, the functions $g(x)$ and $f_r(x)$ are understood to mean $0$ outside their domains of definition.) $\square$

More generally, it is easy following this method to "twist the function to do whatever we want" in the range $(k,k+1)$ for any integer $k$. The difficulty is to "get past the integer values without ruining the desired property". Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that.