# An infinite linear system of equations with an uncountable number $A$ of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, conjectures

I will start with an example to make things clear and avoid confusion :

Take all $x>0$ and
$$\exp(x) = \sum_{-1<n} a_n x^n$$

Now finding $a_n$ can be described as an infinite linear system of equations :

$$a_0 + a_1 1 + a_2 1 + ... = e$$
$$a_0 + a_1 2 + a_2 4 + ... = e^2$$
$$...$$

and for every $x>0$

$$a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... = e^x$$

So we have a countable number of variables and an uncountable number of equations.

Notice there is only *one* unique solution set $a_n$ here.

This leads to :

Conjecture :

An infinite linear system of equations with an uncountable number $A$ of equations, but a countable number $B$ of variables has at most countable ordinal $C$ * Linear independant * solutions, where $C < B$ and *Linear independant* means not a COUNTABLE LINEAR combination of others.

---

Notice that (in contrast) a countable number of (linear) equations with a countable number of variables CAN have an uncountable number of solutions, who are linear independant.

For instance the (formal) taylor series solution to

$f(x) = f(\exp(x))$

has an uncountable number of solutions and it is equivalent to a system of linear equations with a countable number of variables (the taylor coefficients).

Explicitly:
$$t_i = \sum_n \frac{t_n n^i}{n!}$$

And examples without calculus, dynamics or functional equations exist as well.

Comment: Should I have mentioned tetation in the OP or the tag ? It is not cruxial to the question...

Comment: What about a system $\{ 0 \cdot x^{\alpha} = 0\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$, where $\alpha$ is an index (so we have uncountable infinity of equations) and $x$ is a (single) variable?

Comment: @Zeekless then you get the system $0+0+0+..=0$,$0+0+0+...=0$,... So your determinant is $0$ and the equations are not " unique or nice ". But nice comment anyway

Comment: @mick That is my point. The condition of 'niceness' should be included into the conjecture.

Comment: @Zeekless hmm not sure. if you are looking for $a_n$ in $x^{a_n}$ , that is not linear !
If all solutions need to be zero , that is a unique solution ( all zero ); $1$ is countable.

Comment: Does "uncountable many variables" or "uncountable many equations" make sense at all ? Infinite many variables/equations are of course possible , but uncountable many ?

Comment: @Peter is the example from the OP not a good example of it ? Afterall the reals are uncountable. Or maybe you want to say it is overkill and the function and sequence is already definable by a countable number of equations ? But that is the situation of the question.

Comment: A linear system (even an infinite one) must be listable line per line. It can only have countable many lines. And also only countable many variables.

Comment: @Peter why ? What forbids it ??