# Is there a name for equations like $f(n) = f^{(n)}(0) $?

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations

So far, I've encountered three questions here on MSE that involve a function evaluated at a natural argument $n$ on the one left side of the equation, and the same function that has been differentiated $n$ times and evaluated at a constant argument. Examples include the following equations:

1. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91855/is-there-a-function-with-the-property-fn-fn0?rq=1), the titular equation is discussed: $$ f(n) = f^{(n)}(0). \tag{1} $$ Here, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$.
2. The question above is generalized [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397434/is-there-a-function-with-the-property-fn-fna?noredirect=1&lq=1), and asks about real-analytic functions $g(\cdot)$ that satisfy $$ g(n) = g^{(n)}(a) \tag{2} $$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
3. Finally, the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772755/does-there-exist-a-function-that-generates-itself?noredirect=1&lq=1) leads to the equation $$ h(n) = \frac{ h^{(n)}(0) }{ n! }, \tag{3} $$ as pointed out by user Dan in the comment section. The same question was also [posed earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348412/function-fx-such-that-sum-n-0-infty-fn-xn-fx?noredirect=1&lq=1).

All of these equations are of the form $$p(n) = p^{(n)}(a) \ q(n) \tag{*} $$ for some function $q: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{ 0 \} $ and some $p: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. They look a bit like differential equations, but it seems they're also different compared to them.

> **Questions**: do equations of the form $(*)$ have a name? Are they mentioned and described in the literature somewhere?

Comment: They all fall under the bracket of functional differential equations. More specifically, they involve finding functions with self-similar derivatives or generating functions.

Comment: @Jam: Yes. I do hope though that there's a more specific name for this type of equations within the big field of functional differential equations. And I wonder whether they have been studied before -- all references are welcome

Comment: That's a linear delay differential equation ([DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation#Examples)) with a single discrete delay at $x = 0$:
$$
\begin{align*}
f\left( x + n \right) &= \frac{\operatorname{d}^{n}f\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{n}}\\
g\left( x + n \right) &= \frac{\operatorname{d}^{n}g\left( x + a \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{n}}\\
\end{align*}
$$
If $n$ is not an integer then you could think of it as a linear fractional delay differential equation (FDDE) with a single discrete delay at $x = 0$. Does that answer the question / do you mean that??

Comment: @KevinDietrich Hmm yes, it does seem to be related. However, I don't see any higher order derivates on de DDE page you linked to -- do these also appear in the study on DDEs?