# References for equations like $f(n) = f^{(n)}(0) $?

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776366/is-there-a-name-for-equations-like-fn-fn0), I ask about equations like $$ g(n) = g^{(n)}(a) \tag{1} $$
and $$ h(n) = \frac{ h^{(n)}(0) }{ n! }. \tag{2} $$

Equation $(1)$ is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91855/is-there-a-function-with-the-property-fn-fn0?rq=1) for $a=0$, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397434/is-there-a-function-with-the-property-fn-fna?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the general case where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Also, equation $(2)$ is looked into in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772755/does-there-exist-a-function-that-generates-itself?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348412/function-fx-such-that-sum-n-0-infty-fn-xn-fx?noredirect=1&lq=1). Through Kevin Dietrich's suggestion and some research, I've learned that equations like this are called *higher-order delay differential equations*.

I am curious whether there is any literature on this topic that covers such equations extensively. I know there are books on the subject, but the ones I've found fall short on what I am looking for.

For instance, the following book by T. Erneux discusses mostly lower-order delay differential equations, like $\frac{dy}{dt} = ky (t - \tau). $ I am also curious what happens in higher-order cases.

Then there is also a class of papers that delve into higher-order DDEs, but they mostly go into numerical properties or long time behaviour. Examples include [this article](https://www.aimspress.com/article/doi/10.3934/math.2022275) and [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090447915001409).

What I am looking for, are sources that delve into **(a)** meromorphic or analytic solutions to higher-order DDEs ([this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449723000015) provides a rare instance of a relevant source in this sense), and **(b)** look mostly at higher-order DDEs for functions at (positive) integer-valued arguments, like those in equation $(1)$ when $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, and $(2)$.

> **Question**: are there any resources on analytic or meromorphic solutions to higher-order delay differential equations at integer-valued arguments?