# what is exactly analytic continuation of the product log function

Tags: special-functions, lambert-w

When I solve in [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20xe%5Ex=z%20for%20x%20) equation like this $xe^x=z$
they give me the solution $x=W_n(z)$

I know about $x=W_0(z) $ and $x=W_{1}(z)$ but for $n$ I searched in the internet but I didn't find anything can give me an expression about $x=W_n(z)$

Please can anyone help me and give me an explain $x=W_n(z)$ and give me an example how we can find $x=W_n(t)$ $t\in C$ or $t\in R$

Comment: In addition to the nice answer by @GEdgar, if you look at the Wolfram page, in the bottom right-hand corner of the answer block, there is a hyperlink that lets you get pointers to  what this is referring to and it is quite useful (it is labeled $W_k$ in your example (click-the-link and see the different groups of details you can get)) . Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that, and much more, is here:

Corless, R.M.; Gonnet, G.H.; Hare, D.E.G.; Jeffrey, D.J.; and Knuth, D.E. "On the Lambert W Function." Advances in Computational Mathematics, Vol. 5, (1996): 329-359.