# Solve for $x$ in the equation $e^x = 2x $

Tags: logarithms

All I can see so far is: 
$\ln{e^x} = \ln{2x}$ -> $ x = ln{2x} $

How can I solve for x?

Comment: Are you looking for real $x$ or complex $x$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples

Comment: @S.C.B. I do not think this equation has real solutions. Graphing $e^x-2x$ at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d8oueevfh7 shows that it never crosses the $x$-axis, thus the only roots must be complex.

Comment: @MichaelWang Yes, I proved this in my answer. Thus, why I asked this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that as we have that [$e^a \ge a+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504663/simplest-or-nicest-proof-that-1x-le-ex) for all real $a$, by puting $a=x-1$we have that $$e^{x-1} \ge x$$
For all $x$. Thus, multiplying $e$ on each side gives us that $$e^x \ge ex >2x \implies e^x >2x$$
As [$e>2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166310/proving-mathrm-e-3). Hence, there are no real solutions to $e^x=2x$. However, if you were to include complex solutions, note that our equatio is equvialent to  solving $(-x)e^{-x}=-\frac{1}{2}$ $$x=-\mathrm{W}_{n}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Where $\mathrm{W}_{n}$ is the [analytic continuation of the product log function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398433/what-is-exactly-analytic-continuation-of-the-product-log-function).

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does your first inequality come from?

Comment: @mrnovice I know this inequality from experience. The proof is in the link.

Answer (score 2):

$$e^x = 2x$$
$$\text {Take ln of both sides}$$
$$\ln(e^x) = \ln(2x)$$
$$x = \ln(2x)$$

These two do not intersect, thus there is no solution.
[image]

Comment: I don't think that drawing the graph is a proof exactly....

Comment: I simplified as much and I could, and then showed that there is no real solution,